# Argocd Sync issue error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.metadata):

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, debugging, yaml, argocd

I have deployed my app using terraform and I'd like to now sync it to my ArgoCD but I keep getting this error and I can't bypass it.

```
error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.metadata): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta
```

Here's my yaml files.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot
  namespace: call
  labels:
    app: springboot
    admission.datadoghq.com/enabled: "true"
    tags.datadoghq.com/env: "dev"
    tags.datadoghq.com/service: "backend"
    tags.datadoghq.com/version: "0.0.1"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot
        admission.datadoghq.com/enabled: "true"
        tags.datadoghq.com/env: "dev"
        tags.datadoghq.com/service: "backend"
        tags.datadoghq.com/version: "0.0.1"
      annotations:
        admission.datadoghq.com/java-lib.version: "v1.16.2"
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: springboot
          image: northamerica-northeast1-docker.pkg.dev/cal/java-springboot/boot:1.38.
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
              - name: DD_PROFILING_ENABLED
                value: "false"
              - name: DD_LOGS_INJECTION
                value: "true"
              - name: DD_APPSEC_ENABLED
                value: "false"
              - name: DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE
                value: "1"
              - name: COTURN_HOST
                value: "host"
              - name: COTURN_USERNAME
                value: "username"
              - name: COTURN_PASSWORD
                value: "password"
              - name: COTURN_PORT
                value: "80"
          envFrom:
              - configMapRef:
                  name: calconfig
              - secretRef:
                  name: openvidu-secret
              - secretRef:
                  name: jwt-secrets
              - secretRef:
                  name: mail-secrets
              - secretRef:
                  name: db-secrets
```

Is this error related to indentation?